# How do I generate a hash values of 3 arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

Given I have 3 arrays that are mapped to each other.

```
fruit = ['apple', 'avocado', 'banana']
color = ['red', 'purple', 'yellow']
price = [30, 20, 50]
```

How do create an array of hashes with the following value

```
[
 {fruit: 'apple', color: 'red', price: 30},
 {fruit: 'avocado', color: 'purple', price: 20},
 {fruit: 'banana', color: 'yellow', price: 50}
]
```

Comment: Just noticed your input has `inventory`, but you output has `price` - what gives?

Comment: @UriAgassi yes, it should be price.

Comment: What gives the price value in the hash?

Comment: It was unclear, but rubies has clarified with an edit.  It should be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) to interleave the arrays, and then map them into an array of hashes:

```
fruit.zip(color, price).map { |f, c, p| { fruit: f, color: c, price: p } }
# => [{:fruit=>"apple", :color=>"red", :price=>30}, 
# =>  {:fruit=>"avocado", :color=>"purple", :price=>20}, 
# =>  {:fruit=>"banana", :color=>"yellow", :price=>50}
# => ]
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @rubies Your comment here contradicts with your question.

Comment: A variant would be to substitute `[fruit, color, price].transpose` for `fruit.zip(color, price)`.